# How can I change an Element in an array, that contains a specific String?

Tags: arrays, swift, barcode

As it is said in the title I could use some help regarding a problem I have with my App.

My App scans a Barcode and offers to safe this barcode in a table together with a second String that can be put in which describes the number of times you want to save this barcode.

The customInit of the cell displays this as the barcode on the left and a grey number on the right representing the count. All of this information is saved in an array of form list=["972537657, 12"; ...]

My last functionality I want to implement is to have a function check for a maybe already existing barcode in the table and if there is instead of inserting a new row with the same barcode and a different number I want my app to just add the number I put in , to the number of the already existing table element with this specific barcode.

**My problem:** The logic in this works fine ; if there is an already existing element execute this function if not just insert a new row with the input data.

But I Have no idea how to tell the app what to change and how I can access this element of the array.

Maybe someone has an idea (I can also add some of my code if someone would like to inspect my problem further)

Answer (score 1):

First, find the index of the string your looking for, then remove it and insert it at the index.

```
let arr:Array = ["a","b","c"]
let indexOfA = arr.index(of: "a")

arr.remove(at: indexOfA)
arr.insert("YourString", at: indexOfA)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only care about the duplication, why don't use  Set instead of Array.

```
var barcode:Set  = ["972537657","972537651","972537653"]

let  result  =  barcode.insert("972537651")
if result.inserted  {
  print("insert")
}else  {
  print("duplication")
}
```